# a Powershell Script to hash Compare 2 Folders full of video files with sub Folders Inside

Tags: powershell

I Have a folder full of video Files avi ,mp4 ,and even mkv and each file is located Inside a sub folder
which I recently backed it up to an external Hard Drive
I want a powershell script that can create hash for all of the video Files inside that Folder and its subfolders and Compare with the destination Folder on my External hard drive
so I can make sure all of the video files inside the backup folder is exactly the same as source bit by bit .

Edit :I want to be sure all the Files on Source Folder hash match files in backup destination Folder bit by bit
Note :each video file is located inside a subfolder

I tried this Code but it did Not work for me Maybe because every file is located inside a subfolder ?

```
$source = Get-ChildItem –Path \\Plex-SERVER\Media | % { Get-FileHash –Path $_.FullName }
$backup = Get-ChildItem –Path I:\backup\media | % { Get-FileHash –Path $_.FullName }
(Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $source -DifferenceObject $backup -Property hash -Passthru).Path
```

Comment: Is the directory structure important, or do you just need to ensure that all files under FolderA is also present somewhere under FolderB?

Comment: I tried to use this code but it did not work for me maybe because I have each file inside a sub folder ?   $source = Get-ChildItem –Path \\Plex-SERVER\Media | % { Get-FileHash –Path $_.FullName }
$backup = Get-ChildItem –Path I:\backup\media | % { Get-FileHash –Path $_.FullName }
(Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $source -DifferenceObject $backup -Property hash -Passthru).Path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the files are same in each folder:

```
$source      = Get-ChildItem "path of source" -Recurse | Get-FileHash
$destination = Get-ChildItem "path of dest"   -Recurse | Get-FileHash

# Compare source and destination
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $source -DifferenceObject $destination
```

If there are other files present but you only want the special ones:

```
$source      = Get-ChildItem "*.mp4","*.mkv" -Recurse | Get-FileHash
$destination = Get-ChildItem "*.mp4","*.mkv" -Recurse | Get-FileHash

# Compare source and destination
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $source -DifferenceObject $destination
```

Comment: `-Recurse` is the crucial tip, and the tip re wildcard patterns is helpful, but I suggest using the OP's own `Compare-Object` call in your answer, because your current one won't produce meaningful output: In the absence of a `-Property` argument, and in the absence of the `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileHashInfo` instances output by `Get-FileHash` implementing `IComparable`, the instances are compared by their `.ToString()` values, which is  the type's full _name_. That is, even files with _different_ hashes are mistakenly considered equal.