# Compare folder to a hash file

Tags: powershell, file, hash, compare

There are a lot of questions and answers about comparing the hash of two folder for integrity like [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61801465/13826315) Assuming I have a folder that I copied to a backup medium (External drive, flash, optical disc) and would like to **delete the original** to save space.

What is the best way to save the original's folder hashes (before deletion) in a text file perhaps and check the backup's integrity much later against that file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that if you delete the originals *first* and later find that the backup lacks integrity, so to speak, all you'll know is *that* something went wrong; the non-corrupted data will be gone.

---

You can create a CSV file with 2 columns, `RelativePath` (the full file path relative to the input directory) and `Hash`, and save it to a CSV file with [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv):

```sh
$inputDir = 'C:\path\to\dir' # Note: specify a *full* path.
$prefixLen = $inputDir.Length + 1

Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -LiteralPath $inputDir |
  Get-FileHash |
    Select-Object @{ 
                    Name='RelativePath'
                    Expression={ $_.Path.Substring($prefixLen) } 
                  }, 
                  Hash |
    Export-Csv originalHashes.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8
```

<sup>Note: In *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, neither `-NoTypeInformation` nor `-Encoding utf8` are needed, though note that the file will have *no* UTF-8 *BOM*; use `-Encoding utf8bom` if you want one; conversely, in *Windows PowerShell* you *invariably* get a BOM.</sup>

Note:

- The [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileHashInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileHashInfo) instances output by [`Get-FileHash`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash) also have an `.Algorithm` property naming the hashing algorithm that was used (`'SHA256'` by default, or as specified via the `-Algorithm` parameter).
  If you want this property included (whose value will be the same for all CSV rows), you simply add `Algorithm` to the array of properties passed to `Select-Object` above.
- Note how a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) (`@{ ... }`) passed as the second property argument to [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) serves as a [*calculated property*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) that derives the relative path from each `.Path` property value (which contains the *full* path).

You can later apply the same command to the *backup* directory tree, saving to, say, `backupHashes.csv`, and compare the two CSV files with [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object):

```sh
Compare-Object (Import-Csv -LiteralPath originalHashes.csv) `
               (Import-Csv -LiteralPath backupHashes.csv) `
               -Property RelativePath, Hash
```

Note: There's no strict need to involve *files* in the operation - one or both output collections can be captured in memory and can be used directly in the comparison - just omit the `Export-Csv` call in the command above and save to a variable (`$originalHashes = Get-ChildItem ...`)